# Canonical isomorphism $V^{*}/ Ann(W) \cong W^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need to find a canonical isomorpism $V^{*} / Ann (W) \cong W^{*}$, $ W \subset V$

The first approach is: Let's consider a map $\phi: V^{*} \rightarrow W^{*}$, $ker( \phi)=Ann(W) $, then $V^{*} / Ann(W) \cong im(\phi)$.

$dim(im(\phi))=dim(V)-dim(Ann(W))=dim(W)=dim(W^{*})$, then $V^{*} / Ann W \cong W^{*}$.

But how to find a canonical isomorphism?

First, we should denote $V^{*} / Ann (W)$ as a set of classes $[f]=f+ Ann(W)$ and then try to check that the image of a map doesn't depend on the chosen vector from the class. How to cope with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly sketched the proof, we need a map $\phi:V^*\to W^*$.

For $f\in V^*$, i.e. $f:V\to {\Bbb K}$ consider $\phi(f):=f|_W$ the restriction, and observe that indeed $\ker\phi=Ann(W)$.

You also need to prove surjectivity of $\phi$.